# Несколько recapcha на 1 странице

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Обнаружил что нельзя использовать несколько капч на одной странице. Но сам сайт стоит из 1 странице и на нем есть форма регистрации, форма восстановления пароля, форма подтверждения. На всех формах стоит по 1 капче. Сейчас реализовал так :

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
        var onloadCallback = function() {
        mysitekey = 'Ключ';
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
        'sitekey' : mysitekey
        });

        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
        'sitekey' : mysitekey
        });

        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha3', {
        'sitekey' : mysitekey
        });

        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha4', {
        'sitekey' : mysitekey
        });
        };
    </script>
```

Ну и

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha1"></div>
```

Все чудесно работает, но последние время некоторые пользователи начали жаловаться что капча не отображается, я проверил у меня все отображалось, я все списал на adblock, но начал проверять периодически и действительно, капча не отображалась. Сделав несколько танцев с бубном, почистив кеш историю и тд, она снова отобразилась, потом снова пропала, сейчас вроде отображается. Что это такое, как с этим бороться? Плиз только не советуйте переписать все под отдельные страницы :((

Comment: Почему нельзя на все формы сделать одну общую капчу?

Comment: а сайт на чем сам? не asp.net mvc случайно?

Comment: @tCode php, самописный.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Страницы сделаны всплывающими окнами, у каждого окошка своя капча.

Comment: @Winteriscoming Так страница одна или несколько?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov одна, дивы спрятанные всплывают по клику по ссылкам. Обмен с сервером через ajax.

Comment: @Winteriscoming если одна, то что мешает сделать одну капчу?